# CNTK.GPU conflicts with CNTK.CpuEval-mkl

Tags: c#, dll, linker, nuget, cntk

I was previously using the NuGet package Microsoft.Research.CNTK.CpuEval-mkl to evaluate some models, until I ran into problems with CPU speed. At that point I switched over to the CNTK.GPU library.

Unfortunately, I noticed a marked decrease in the efficacy of my models, so I suspect that I did something wrong. Just to compare, I would like to run both versions within a single application, have it output the raw evaluation results of each and compare them.

Sadly, when building I get messages about missing DLLs. Which ones are missing depend on which NuGet package was added first. If I add the GPU one first, I get the following list:
 - Cntk.Core-2.0rc1.dll
 - cudart64_80.dll
 - curand64_80.dll
 - cusparse64_80.dll
 - cudnn64_5.dll
 - cublas64_80.dll
 - Cntk.Core.CSBinding-2.0rc1.dll
 - nvml.dll

If I add the CPU version first, then only one DLL is missing:
 - Ctnk.Eval-2.0rc1.dll

Is there a way to force the two to work together, or do I need to run two separate applications and manually compare the output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not a supported scenario to install both Nuget pacages to the same application. You might get it work with manually adding references to your project, but we have never tried and tested this.

Thanks,

Comment: Thank you, I ended up creating a couple of utility libraries with identical interfaces; that way I could just change which project my test referenced.